# Issue with creating a new user to my database with time of creation in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

When attempting to create a new user to add to a database, it never actually adds them to the database, though if I attempt to with all the date and time sections removed it has no problem adding them to the database.

This is the code - server name has been removed on purpose.

```
<?php

     $server = ''; 
     $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"rde_506134"); 
     $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
     $dateAndTime = date('d/m/y/ h:i:a', time());
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
     $surname = $_POST['surname'];
     $location = $_POST['location'];
     $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, firstname, surname, location, dateandtime)
     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
     $params = array($username, $firstname, $surname, $location, $dateAndTime);
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);

     {
     echo $username;
     echo " has been successfully created for ";
     echo $firstname;
     echo " ";
     echo $surname;
     echo " at location ";
     echo $location;
     echo " at ";
     echo $dateAndTime;
     echo ".";
     }
     sqlsrv_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: rather than inserting the value for `dateandtime`, change the column type in the database to `timestamp` with a default value of `current_timestamp` perhaps - though I just noticed that it is `sql server` rather than `mysql` so that would likely be different, probably default `GETDATE()`

Comment: What datatype is your datetime column because the format appears to have an extra "/" in it after the year

Comment: the datatype is datetime - i tried removing the extra "/" though that changed nothing

Comment: What is the value of $result after making the insert call?

Comment: I reckon it's the formatting for the date string that's throwing it out. Could you try: `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`.

Comment: There is no value when i echo the $result to check it

Comment: I think you're right Steve, when I changed it to that it now creates the user thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to format the timestamp differently:

```
$dateAndTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

(As [Steve Lovell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3751420/steve-lovell) has correctly pointed out in his comment)